# Split website url into multiple columns into scala dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a column which has many URL as below:

[image]

I need to `split` this columns on `"."` and the task is to get the following o/p:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code.

You can ignore length column, it is used to decide max number columns

```
scala> val df = Seq("www.google.co.kr","jun.artcompsci.org","mstdn.pssy.flab.fujitsu.cojp").toDF("URL")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [URL: string]

scala> val adf = df.withColumn("url_array",split($"URL","\\.")).withColumn("length",size($"url_array")).orderBy($"length".desc)
adf: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [URL: string, url_array: array<string> ... 1 more field]

scala> val length = adf.select("length").head.getInt(0)
length: Int = 5

scala> adf.select($"*" +: (0 until length).map(i => $"url_array".getItem(i).as(s"col$i")): _*).show(false)
+----------------------------+----------------------------------+------+-----+----------+----+-------+----+
|URL                         |url_array                         |length|col0 |col1      |col2|col3   |col4|
+----------------------------+----------------------------------+------+-----+----------+----+-------+----+
|mstdn.pssy.flab.fujitsu.cojp|[mstdn, pssy, flab, fujitsu, cojp]|5     |mstdn|pssy      |flab|fujitsu|cojp|
|www.google.co.kr            |[www, google, co, kr]             |4     |www  |google    |co  |kr     |null|
|jun.artcompsci.org          |[jun, artcompsci, org]            |3     |jun  |artcompsci|org |null   |null|
+----------------------------+----------------------------------+------+-----+----------+----+-------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the task as follow.

```scala
package tests


import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object UrlSplitToDataframe {

  val spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("UrlSplitToDataframe")
    .master("local")
    .config("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions","8") //Change to a more reasonable default number of partitions for our data
    .getOrCreate()

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  def lstFillNulls(lStr: List[String], len: Int) :List[String] = {
    @tailrec
    def loop(lst: List[String], ln: Int, acc: List[String]): List[String] = {
      ln match {
        case 0 => acc.reverse
        case _ => {
          lst match {
            case Nil => loop(Nil, ln - 1, "null" :: acc)
            case _ => loop(lst.tail, ln - 1, lst.head :: acc)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    loop(lStr, len, Nil)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    Logger.getRootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    try {
      import spark.implicits._
      var maxSize = 0
      val data = Seq("www.google.co.kr","jun.artcompsci.org","mstdn.pssy.flab.fujitsu.cojp")
        .map(uri =>{
          val lst = uri :: uri.split('.').toList
          if(maxSize < lst.length) maxSize = lst.length
          lstFillNulls(lst, maxSize).toArray
        })

      val df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF()
      val uris = df
        .select((0 until maxSize).map(index => col("value").getItem(index).as(s"column$index")): _*)
      uris.show(false)
      
    } finally {
      sc.stop()
      println("SparkContext stopped")
      spark.stop()
      println("SparkSession stopped")
    }
  }
}
```

ouput

```sql
+----------------------------+-----+----------+----+-------+----+
|column0                     |column1|column2|column3|column4|column5|
+----------------------------+-----+----------+----+-------+----+
|www.google.co.kr            |www  |google    |co  |kr     |null|
|jun.artcompsci.org          |jun  |artcompsci|org |null   |null|
|mstdn.pssy.flab.fujitsu.cojp|mstdn|pssy      |flab|fujitsu|cojp|
+----------------------------+-----+----------+----+-------+----+
```

or with `SparkSQL`

```scala
myDf.createOrReplaceTempView("table")
sqlContext.sql("""
               SELECT url,
                     IF(SIZE(SPLIT(url,'\\.')) > 1, SPLIT(url,'\\.')[0], 'NA') as Col1,
                         IF(SIZE(SPLIT(url,'\\.')) > 2, SPLIT(url,'\\.')[1], 'NA') as Col2,
                         IF(SIZE(SPLIT(url,'\\.')) > 3, SPLIT(url,'\\.')[2], 'NA') as Col3,
                         .....
                         IF(SIZE(SPLIT(url,'\\.')) > 6, SPLIT(url,'\\.')[5], 'NA') as Col6
               FROM table
               """)
```